# Convert DECODE into mapping / reference table

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I want to make sure that this conversion of a `DECODE` function into a `SELECT` statement joining it to a mapping table would run properly and I'm not using coding or format that works in SQL Server but is different in Oracle SQL

About the code: it is using the `DECODE` function to map a series of four digit medical taxonomy codes into two digit provider specialty codes. The primary table is `PRVDR.TXNMY_CD`, the outcome would be a column `PRFRM_PRVDR_SPCLTY_CD`.

Original code:

```
SELECT 
    DECODE (SUBSTR(PRVDR.TXNMY_CD, 1, 4),
           '261Q', '70','347E', '59','332H', '96','332B', 'A6','1711', 'Y9','2257', 'Y9','106H', '62','103K', '26','101Y', '26','367A', '42','207K', '03', '3416', '59','367H', '32','207L', '05','211D', '48','231H', '64','2376', '64','111N', '35','291U', '69','103G', '86','364S', '89','208C', '28', '172V', '60','251S'
           ) END AS PRFRM_PRVDR_SPCLTY_CD
FROM 
    NPS_CLM_HDR
```

My conversion attempt:

First, I'd separately create this table called MAPPING with the following columns

```
| TXNMY_CD_MAP | PRFRM_PRVDR_SPCLTY_CD |
| 1711         | Y9                    |
| 2257         | Y9                    |
| 106H         | 62                    |
| 367A         | 42                    |

    etc.
```

Then I would use the following query:

```
SELECT PRFRM_PRVDR_SPCLTY_CD
FROM REF.MAPPING AS M
JOIN PRVDR.TXNMY_CD AS P ON P.TXNMY_CD = M.TXNMY_CD_MAP
```

Does this look correct or have I used terminology from SQL Server that does not work with Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I am expecting the two columns to be:

```
TXNMY_CD4  PRFRM_PRVDR_SPCLTY_CD
'261Q'      '70'
'347E'      '59'
'332H'      '96'
. . .
```

This *may* be what your table looks like, but these are the values at the beginning of the table.

And then:

```
SELECT m.PRFRM_PRVDR_SPCLTY_CD
FROM PRVDR.TXNMY_CD P LEFT JOIN
     REF.MAPPING M
     ON LEFT(P.TXNMY_CD, 4) = M.TXNMY_CD_MAP
```

Except for the `LEFT()` vs. `SUBSTR()`, this should work in both databases.

Note that this uses `LEFT JOIN` to ensure that no rows are lost, even if there are no matches.

Answer (score 0):

`decode()` is an Oracle function, that is not available in SQL Server. If you wanted to translate your `decode` to SQL Server, you would use `case`:

```
case left(prvdr.txnmy_cd, 4)
    when '261Q' then '70'
    when '347E' then '59'
    ...
end as prfrm_prvdr_spclty_cd
from nps_clm_hdr
```

Note that `substr()` is not supported in SQL Server - here we cause `left()` instead.

That said, using a mapping table is a better approach: it scales better, and makes it easy to maintain the mapping (there is no need to modify the code of the query, just the data).

You would phrase the query as:

```
select prfrm_prvdr_spclty_cd
from prvdr.txnmy_cd as p
left join ref.mapping as m on left(p.txnmy_cd, 4) = m.txnmy_cd_map
```

The `left join` allows unmapped values.

Not all database support `left()`, nor `substr()` (it is sometimes called `substring()`, as in SQL Server). I think that the most portable approach uses `like` and `concat()`:

```
left join ref.mapping as m on p.txnmy_cd like concat(m.txnmy_cd_map, '%')
```